# Assign an event to multiple calendars, one shared calendar and another topic related calendar which is not shared

Tags: google-calendar

I want to assign an event to multiple calendars without making a duplicate the event in each calendar. I need to share one calendar with family and coworkers for scheduling purposes, but not share all events from each topic related calendar. I can make a duplicate copy of the event to add to my shared calendar, but this clutters up my calendar. The simple fix is to duplicate the event to my shared calendar then deselect my shared calendar from my view to remove the clutter. Not the elegant way to solve the problem, and I was hoping for a more efficient solution to my issue. Does anyone have an answer for this?

Answer (score 3):

Google Calendar does not provide a way to merge the same event that appears in multiple calendars, and Google has been [blatantly](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/calendar/bOSfyMmWIRc/e5K5uUdC5SoJ) ignoring [requests to do so dating as far back as 2009](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/66899/17089)

The only solution might be to use a Chrome extension, [gcal-multi-event-merge](https://github.com/imightbeamy/gcal-multical-event-merge)**, which unfortunately [doesn't work in the monthly view](https://github.com/imightbeamy/gcal-multical-event-merge/issues/3). For the 1 and 4-day views, and for the weekly view, it works great:

[image]

Comment: As suggested here https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/VLpt10m0StA;context-place=topicsearchin/calendar/duplicated$20across$20multiple please submit feedback to google directly. This add-on, doesn't really fix the problem especially if you want a coherent experience on mobile as well as desktop.