# Merge duplicate events in shared Google calendars

Tags: google-calendar

In my Google Calendar I have visibility over several shared calendars. If multiple people who share calendars with me attend the same event, I can see the event quite a few times.

Example screenshot:

[image]

**Question:** Is there a way to change my settings such that I can see all shared calendars, but it will condense identical events into a single entry?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Google Calendar does not provide a way to merge the same event that appears in multiple calendars, and Google has been oblivious to requests to do so dating as far back as 2009 -

- [Sharing Calendars creates duplicate events](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/FTX_rKsgDSw) - 2009-Jan, closed
- [General ability to hide events in shared calendars](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!newtopic/calendar/calendar/W8jpiJZ_2Gs) - 2010-Jun
- [Suggestion: hide 'duplicate' event on shared calendars](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/_GL_oMv5Ya8) - 2013-Mar, closed
- [Hide events on a shared calendar of mutual attendees](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!searchin/calendar/duplicate$20events$20shared/calendar/PYCO_2cTpN4/3TCO0iTE3W4J) - 2013-Jul, closed
- [2014 Hide events duplicated across multiple calendars thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/calendar/bOSfyMmWIRc/2iDR10NvBhoJ) - April 2014 request, summarizing years of previous requests. Closed.
- ... and the only active thread - [Feature request: ability to hide events in shared calendars](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/calendar/KotIeda_uCU/VRSfDcysfb8J)

The only **solution is to use a Chrome extension, [gcal-multi-event-merge](https://github.com/imightbeamy/gcal-multical-event-merge)**

[image: gcal-multical-event-merge]

Answer (score 0):

Try out the Google Chrome Extension (new link) here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/event-merge-for-google-ca/idehaflielbgpaokehlhidbjlehlfcep

Comment: This is actually the same as the previous answer, but thanks! :)